# Objects Not Working In Sub

Tags: function, object, vbscript

In our code, we have a few Excel objects and a few subs and functions.

We edited a few things and now, for some reason, our objects aren't working inside the sub, the give a "Object Required" error.

We don't know what to do anymore, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Note: We added the entire code in case there would be questions about declarations and that...

Sub:

Sub birthday (formatDate, i, intRow)

```
'Take date from database, separate it to days & months
Dim month, day, name
eventDate = Split(formatDate,"/")
month = eventDate(0)
day = eventDate(1)

'Get name of event out of database (one column to the right, from date of event)
name = "netch"

'Get value of row which is used to write events in the specific month
Dim k, row, c
k = 1
wscript.echo objXLCal.Cells(k, 2).Value
Do Until objXLCal.Cells(k, 2).Value = monthRet(month)
    k = k + 1
Loop

'k will be used to find the day column, while row is where the events of that months are written
row = k + 3
c = 1

'Get value of column
Do Until objXLCal.Cells(k,c).Value = eval(day)
    c = c + 1
Loop

'Insert name of event into place
If Asc(name) = 63 Then
    objXLCal.Cells(row,c).Value = StrReverse(name)
Else
    objXLCal.Cells(row,c).Value = name
End If
End Sub
```

Rest of code:

```
main("C:\Users\liatte\Desktop\hotFolder\Input")
Function main(argFilePath)

Dim templatePath
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Path to calendar template
templatePath = "C:\Users\liatte\Desktop\Aviv Omer Neta\Birthdays\Calendar1.xlsx"
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

'creates the msxml object
'Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
'Dim retVal

'load the xml data of the script
'retVal=xmlDoc.load(argFilePath)

Dim fso, folder, sFolder, inputFolder, xmlDataPath, curNode

'get input folder
'Set curNode=xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("//ScriptXmlData/inputFilePath")
'inputFolder=CSTR(curNode.text)

'location of input folder
'sFolder=inputFolder
sFolder=argFilePath

'creating file getting object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folder = fso.GetFolder(sFolder)

'loop that runs on files in input - RUNS JUST ONCE
'For each folderIdx In folder.files

    'Creating object for user excel
    Set objXLBirth = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set objWorkbookBirth = objXLBirth.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\liatte\Desktop\hotFolder\Input\Birthdays.xlsx")

    'Creating object for calendar template excel
    Set objXLCal = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    objXLCal.DisplayAlerts = false

    Dim picStr, srcMonth, k, i, intRow, formatDate, txtStr

    'Beginning reading from line 2, skipping header
    intRow = 2

    'loop for each person in user excel
    Do Until objXLBirth.Cells(intRow,1).Value = ""
        i=2

        'Opening the template as new in each round of loop
        Set objWorkbookCal = objXLCal.Workbooks.Open(templatePath)

        'Cover pic
        If Not objXLBirth.Cells(intRow, i).Value = "" Then
            objXLCal.Cells(2, 49).Value = objXLBirth.Cells(intRow, i).Value
        End If

        'Month pic inserter
        For i=3 To 14
            If Not objXLBirth.Cells(intRow,i).Value = "" Then
                picStr = objXLBirth.Cells(1,i).Value
                srcMonth = monthRet(Mid(picStr,4))

                k=1
                Do Until objXLCal.Cells(k, 2).Value = srcMonth
                    k=k+1
                Loop
                objXLCal.Cells(k, 47).Value = objXLBirth.Cells(intRow,i).Value
            End If
        Next

        i=15

        'Cover text inserter
        If Not objXLBirth.Cells(intRow, i).Value = "" Then
            objXLCal.Cells(2, 50).Value = objXLBirth.Cells(intRow, i).Value
        End If

        'Month text inserter
        For i = 16 To 27
            If Not objXLBirth.Cells(intRow,i).Value = "" Then
                txtStr = objXLBirth.Cells(1,i).Value
                srcMonth = monthRet(Mid(txtStr,5))

                k=1
                Do Until objXLCal.Cells(k, 2).Value = srcMonth
                    k=k+1
                Loop
                If Asc(objXLBirth.Cells(intRow, i).Value)=63 Then
                    objXLCal.Cells(k, 48).Value = StrReverse(objXLBirth.Cells(intRow, i).Value)
                Else
                    objXLCal.Cells(k, 48).Value = objXLBirth.Cells(intRow, i).Value
                End If
            End If
        Next

        i=28

        'Birthday inserter
        Do Until objXLBirth.Cells(intRow,i).Value = ""
            formatdate=FormatDateTime(objXLBirth.Cells(intRow,i),2)
            Call birthday (formatdate,i,intRow)
            i=i+2
        Loop

        'saving changed calendar
        objXLCal.ActiveWorkBook.SaveAs "C:\Users\liatte\Desktop\Aviv Omer Neta\Birthdays\Calendar_" & objXLBirth.Cells(intRow, 1).Value & ".txt", 42
        intRow = intRow+1
    Loop

    'moving file to Success
    'fso.MoveFile inputFolder, "C:\Users\liatte\Desktop\Success\"
'Next

objXLBirth.Quit
objXLCal.Quit
End Function
```

Another function:

```
Function monthRet(month)
Select Case month
    Case "1"
        monthRet="January"
    Case "2"
        monthRet="February"
    Case "3"
        monthRet="March"
    Case "4"
        monthRet="April"
    Case "5"
        monthRet="May"
    Case "6"
        monthRet="June"
    Case "7"
        monthRet="July"
    Case "8"
        monthRet="August"
    Case "9"
        monthRet="September"
    Case "10"
        monthRet="October"
    Case "11"
        monthRet="November"
    Case "12"
        monthRet="December"
End Select
End Function
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Given a code layout like:

```
Sub birthday (formatDate, i, intRow)
  ...
  wscript.echo objXLCal.Cells(k, 2).Value
  ...
End Sub

Function main(argFilePath)
  ...
  Set objXLCal = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  ...
End Function

main "C:\Users\liatte\Desktop\hotFolder\Input"
```

an "Object required" error for the WScript.Echo line is to be expected (the local variable objXLCal initialized in main isn't the same as the (therefore) uninitialized local variable objXLCal in birthday).

The correct solution would be to start with "Option Explicit" and follow the principles of decent procedural programming in VBScript, but the disgusting hack of `Dim`ing variables like objXLCal at the top/global level won't lower the quality of the published code.

Comment: Encapsulation usually is a good thing. In the given scenario there's nothing wrong with treating application objects as global singletons, though.